# assign subset of Java list without using iteration loop

Tags: java, list

I have a class with a list of attributes

```
class First {
    private int B;
    private int C;
    private int D;
    private int E;
...
}
```

Then, I have a second class which is a subset of the first

```
class Second {
    private int C;
    private int D;
    }
```

What I would like to do is something like:

```
List<Second> = List<First>
```

In other words, the second list is a subset of the first. What I would like to do is an assignment without having to go through loops or using "add" statements.

Is this possible?

TIA

**Update**
 I had forgotten to mention that the class with the larger number of fields/attribures was a type of "entity" class whose purpose is to  fetch/save data to the database. The Java file itself was created by Hibernate and each of the fields/attribues of the class matches a field in the database. The reason for having a subset 2 types of classes was that the one with lower number of fields/attributes (i.e. the subset) was to be used for REST purposes (i.e. sending data back and forth).

Comment: this assignment will never be allowed by the compiler

Comment: thanks! Working with Java 1.7 now, would like to try the 1.8 option when I get a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, using inheritance:

```
class Second {
    int c, d;
    public int getC() { return c; }
    public int getD() { return d; }
}

class First extends Second {
    int a, b;

    public int getA() { return a; }
    public int getB() { return b; } 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<First> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<? extends Second> secondList = firstList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! - I did some rudimentary tests with this and it looks like it will do the job :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you give `Second` a constructor that takes a `First` argument (and either make the fields visible to `Second` or add visible getters) like

```
class Second {
    public Second(First a) {
        this.C = a.C;
        this.D = a.D;
    }

    private int C;
    private int D;
}
```

And you are using Java 8+, you could stream your `List` of the `First` type and `map` to `Second`(s) like

```
List<First> firsts = new ArrayList<>();
// ...
List<Second> al = firsts.stream().map(Second::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```